# IE8 Binding error

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

I receive the following error in IE8 when trying to data-bind a `<input>` tag:

> Unable to parse bindings.
>
> Message: [object Error];
>
> Bindings value: enable: $root.hasTag('foo')

Essentially, I have an enable data-bind on a checkbox that should disable the checkbox if there are no models with a specific tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: $root.hasTag('foo')" value="foo" 
    class="filtercheck" />
```

The viewmodel has the following method to loop through all models and sum up the models with a matching tag, if the value is greater than 0, then return true.

```
self.hasTag = function(tag) {
    var sum = 0;
    var item;
    for (var i=0; i<this.items().length; i++) {
        item = this.items()[i];
        if (item.tags().indexOf(tag) != -1) {
            sum++;
        } else {
            continue;
        }        
    }
    return (sum > 0) ? true : false;
};
```

Why does this data-bind throw an error in only IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because indexOf isn't defined in IE8. Did a quick test and it returns undefined. You will have to [supply your own version](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX16).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may be right, I'll give it a try. I probably would need to use knockoutjs [observableArray.indexOf](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#indexof)

Comment: Yep that's an option. You can use the ko.utils.arrayIndexOf on non-observable arrays also.